# Runtime compatibility for library packaging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compatibility, nuget-package, msvcrt

I want to package a library as a NuGet native package. This question is not specific to a way in which the packaged lib/dll/pdb/includes are distributed; but to be specific, I am looking at [CoApp scripts](http://coapp.org/index.html) (I wish there was something better I could link to), and I got an impression that there are too many different build targets, obtained combinatorially. I am trying to come up with a more or less minimal set of targets that is usable by applications that depend on the package. There are the following mostly orthogonal axes for build targets:

1. 32 bit vs 64 bit. Obviously, this is legit.
2. Dynamic vs static builds. This is also sensible.
3. Debug vs. Release build. This also makes perfect sense, as debug builds reference the debug runtime (`libcmtd.lib` or `msvcdrtd.lib`) and the release builds reference the static runtime (`libcmtd.lib` or `msvcdrtd.lib`). Makes sense to include these to avoid a default library conflict.

The above are unquestionably good axes. The next one is questionable, although present in many examples:

4. `_cdecl` vs `_stdcall` vs `__fastcall` vs `__thiscall`. I think this makes little sense. The calling conventions would be supported for this particular library regardless of other linked libraries. Besides, variable arguments are for `_cdecl` only in Win32, and also 64 bit calling conventions are [different anyway](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms235286.aspx). My understanding is that anything I select will do, as long as header files declare a calling conventions compatible with the platform. Microsoft runtime libraries are not supplied for different calling conventions in any case.

And the next one I am not sure how to handle. Again, the examples declare

5. libraries build by different *toolsets*, which come with different Visual Studio versions: from `v100` (v10.0, VS 2010) to `vs140` (v14.0, VS 2015). My main question is, how compatible are the runtime libraries across different Visual C++ libraries? A problem here is we are using also other toolsets (Intel C++ is an example), and these usually have no corresponding packaging cases in CoApp, while being compatible with Microsoft runtimes.

I want to avoid packaging for a particular toolset. How possible is that, provided the code compiles with the oldest vesrion and also not using any newer runtime functions (e. g., v110 being the lowest supported version)? I am worried about two main things here (sorry, another numbered list starts here):

1. If I compile a static library with VS 2012 (provided bithood, staticity and debugness match), will I be able to link against it in VS2013 (its `libcmt[d].lib`)?
2. Under same conditions, will I be able to link against it in VS2010?
3. Same two questions, but speaking of a shared, DLL runtime?
4. Same questions, but taking into account runtime library defined exceptions that might be thrown by the library: will e. g. `std` exceptions be compatible up and down the version chain of the compilers, provided I compile the library with RTTI enabled?

More generally, is there a runtime compatibility matrix provided by Microsoft?

And if any other numbered list points, I'd like to hear that too.